# Change button background image programmatically

Tags: android, assets

Iam writing some app on Android. I need to change my button background via code. I have sth like this, but background stay transparent. What is the best way to asset some images and get it into code?

```
   InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/res/drawable/my_icon.png");
   this.btn.setBackground(Drawable.createFromStream(is, ""));
```

Comment: Define custom selector.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use InputStream to do that. Just use the following:

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_icon);
```

Answer (score 1):

your activity.xml:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:id="@+id/background"

    />
```

add this to activity.java:

```
Button mBtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.background);
        mBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_icon);
```